# How to run 2 ear files on jboss 7 with different configurations

Tags: java, jboss7.x, ear

I have a Jboss 7.1.1 installation  and I want to deploy 2 EAR files on it, each one runs in a different instance with different standalone.xml configuration, what will be the best way to do it ?

What i thought of is to define 2 different deployment definitions for the 2 apps, which means to change this section:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
        <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
    </subsystem>
```

Is that the way to go or is there a better way?

Comment: What is the need to use different standalone.xml configurations?

Comment: As I tried to explain in my question (and obviously didn't do a good job at it) , I have 2 applications that are not related to each other and have different configuration needs, so each one needs its own standalone.xml. I'm aware that it is possible to put all in one file but then it will be harder to maintain and to differentiate one configuration from the other. But this is off topic, the main issue here is how to deploy them in different instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a deployment scanner that uses a property, say "my.deploy.dir" and specify that when starting each instance of your standalone server.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
    <deployment-scanner name="myDeployDir" path="${my.deploy.dir}" />
</subsystem>
```

You will specify the value for the property during startup using a property file or with a -D.

```
bin/standalone.sh -P propFile_that_has_my.deploy.dir_value

bin/standalone.sh -Dmy.deploy.dir=myDeployDir1
```

You can also define another configuration file like your original post.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you check out domain mode rather than standalone. If that is too complex or just overkill I suppose using the `--server-config` argument would work. You would just have to make sure that each configurations is set to bind to a different address.

Server one:

```
[jperkins@jperkins-rh jboss-as-7.1.1.Final]$ bin/standalone.sh --server-config standalone.xml
```

Server two:

```
[jperkins@jperkins-rh jboss-as-7.1.1.Final]$ bin/standalone.sh --server-config standalone-full.xml
```

You could also use the `-b xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` and `-Djboss.bind.address.management=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` options if you'd just like to test it.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for trying to help but again, that is not what i meant, I know how to define it to run with different configuration, what i need is for Jboss to take the 2 EAR files from 2 different places. I don't want both of the EAR files to reside under the deployments folder because then it will deploy both of them automatically.

Comment: Why not just deploy them then? Your only other option is to create another deployment scanner.